# maintaining a record of sql inserts

Tags: sql, mysql, database

Is it possible with a mysql script, full of just mysql commands that  get filtered into the mysql binary, to do a count of current records in insert into a stats table, perhaps with the time and date automatically generated?

I would want to do this, so calculations could be done, eg work out the total number of new records inserted in a given time.

Comment: what you want to accomplish is not so clear, could you explain? Are you trying to get the number of inserts in a given time frame on a specific table?

Comment: I want to keep a record every time I make an insert which is daily, and then generate a weekly report...

Answer (score 1):

If you are interested in benchmarking your insert statements, you might be able to get what you want by looking at the [general query log file](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/query-log.html).  It should show you the date and time of each query executed upon the database.  If that isn't sufficient, you might also try looking at the [binary log file](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/binary-log.html).  That might contain information about how many rows were affected by each query.